# Is there a particular reason that EasyJet uses U2 as their code?

Tags: airline-operations

Does anyone know why EasyJet uses **U2** as the prefix for flight numbers? Other airlines have more logical prefixes. Eg. **KL** -> KLM, **AZ** -> Alitalia, **BA**-> British Airways, etc. Even though they do not always match the airline name exactly, they do mimic the name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EZY (EasyJet UK) code and EZS (EasyJet Switzerland)are the ICAO codes, whereas U2 is the code generated by IATA for them when they applied for an IATA code.

http://www.easyjet.com/ejcms/cache/medialibrary/files/travel%20agent%20online%20guides/en/amadeus

**EasyJet Airline Company Limited (UK Based)** - (IATA code: U2; ICAO code: EZY; Callsign: Easy) 
**EasyJet Switzerland SA** (IATA code: DS; ICAO code: EZS; Callsign: TOPSWISS)

ICAO codes are used for operational purposes like flight planning, ATC, etc. **IATA codes like U2** are generally used in timetables, reservation systems, departure/arrival information, etc. - in other words information that is meant for the general public.

Answer (score 11):

Easyjet got their IATA code fairly late on, and as such could not use EZ (which was in use by Sun Air), so they were randomly issued their IATA code of U2.

They do have the three letter code of EZY, just as British Airways has BAW as well as BA.

Comment: The 2 letter IATA code is the airline code.  The flight callsign is the 3 letter code so Easyjet callsigns are "EZY321", pronounced "Easy 3-2-1".

Comment: The three letter code is the ICAO designation, and airlines are free to use either their two letter code or three letter code for call signs.  British Airways uses "Speed Bird 123" as their call sign for most flights, and BA123 for the flight number.

Comment: I think you are wrong.  Can you give any example of the the IATA code being using in a call sign?

Comment: @Moo, the call sign is _written_ using the ICAO code on the flight plan, because flight plans are governed by ICAO. The spoken form uses a radiotelephony designator instead, which may not be related to either the code nor the airline name, as evidenced by BA's "Speedbird" and former PanAm's "Clipper". Note, that the call sign _usually_ is the flight number, but not always. You can have flight BA123 with call sign BAW55B, which would then be spoken as "speedbird five five bravo". Also don't forget that these days most flights have more then one flight number due to code-sharing.